# mustache loop over dict of items without a name (by index)

Tags: python, mustache, handlebars.js, pystache

heres my dict:

```
{   
1: {   'A': u'Eggs',
       'B': 1400,
       'C': u'Jibber',
       'D': u'355'},
2: {   'A': u'Avocados',
       'B': 1000,
       'C': u'Jabber',
       'D': u'356'},
..}
```

Template.mustache

```
{{#each}}
   <li><strong>{{A}}</strong></li>
   <li><strong>{{B}}</strong></li>
...
{{/each}}


{{#empty}}
 <p>The list is empty.</p>
{{/empty}}
```

If the variable is called data, how do I iterate over its items if they are only identifiable by index?

Comment: such a dumb question or genuinely unsolvable! which is it folks?